# Can I calculate the number of patients in experimental and control group based on HR?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, hazard, meta-regression, proportional-hazards

I would like to conduct the meta-analysis of randomized clinical trials. In some of them in the subgrup analysis the number of patients in experimental group (*Ne*) and control group (*Nc*) are not given, however the total number of patients in both group is given. **Can I caluculate *Ne* and *Nc* based on the overall number of patients in subgroup (*Ne+Nc*), HR and its confidence interval?**

As non-mathematician I would really appreciate any Excel- or R-based solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place?

Comment: Please edit your question to spell out "HR".

Comment: Assume HR is Hazard Ratio but it should be spelled.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you gave us a concrete example of (a) what you have (b) what you would like to have (c) why you would like to have it.

Comment: As far as I am aware no, as the HR does not simply depend on the final number of patients with events and at risk, but on the overall summary of instantaneous hazards.

Comment: Voting to close this as unclear since the OP never came back to clarify